# RibbonXML Custom "About" Menu

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

We're developing a vertical ISV offering. It would be nice to have a custom "About" menu item that would display an HTML web resource with our branding and solution information, called from the following location.

[image: Preferred placement]

But I can't find that location in the RibbonXML.

Anyone know how I can get to that place in the application navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to customize that menu using *supported Dynamics CRM customizations*.

**Q: What means supported Dynamics CRM customizations?**

A: Microsoft Dynamics CRM can be customized but it is necessary to follow the [Microsoft Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328350.aspx).

**Q: Why editing that menu is not a supported customization?**

A: Microsoft [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328350.aspx#Unsupported): *Anything that is not documented in the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK and supporting documents is not supported*. Inside the SDK there is no documentation regarding the edit of that menu.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @TJ I know the Dynamics CRM platform and that menu is not customizable, if you know the platform feel free to provide an answer

Comment: Like what is already mentioned in that system generated comment: that is not an answer for the question. You can comment below the question  saying it's not possible as per your knowledge.  *"This is not Possible"* - is not an answer in my opinion.

Comment: well if i had seen this before i might have skipped the review. It's upto the rest to decide now...

Comment: FWIW, the original response was enough of an answer for me. I'm experienced in the field and needed a pointer to something which turns out doesn't exist. But I take the point that single line answers may not help others who need more information.